# retrieve custom char with charcode android

Tags: android, android-fonts

I'm using a custom font with characters like star, sun, etc.

I know their charcode into this font.

I set the TextView font with the following code:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public MyTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public void init() {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font/myFont.ttf");
    setTypeface(tf ,1);

}}
```

is there a way, since I know their charcode, to use those specific characters directly in strings.xml and programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference characters by their 4 digit hexadecimal code in java :

```
String someString = "\u2776"
```

Or in resources :

```
<string name="some_string_name">\u2776</string>
```

(2776 is the code for ❶ in the default font)